# CallByName works with MsgBox but Not When Assigning a Value ("Object Required" Error)

Tags: vba, class, variables, properties

Using VBA in excel:

I have a function where I want to access class properties using variables for property names.  I was able to use a variable with CallByName to MsgBox the property value back to me:

```
MsgBox CallByName(oThisInvoice, DataType, VbGet)
```

Where oThisInvoice is a class object and DataType is the variable that contains the property name I want to access.  This statement works and is a rewrite of:

```
MsgBox oThisInvoice.InvoiceDate
```

However, using the same method doesn't work when assigning a value to the same property:

```
CallByName(oThisInvoice, DataType, VbGet) = 5
```

doesn't work, I get an "Run-time Error 424: Object Required" error.  Using VbLet and VbSet didn't work either, throwing "Run-time error 446: Object doesn't support named arguments".

It is a rewrite of the following:

```
oThisInvoice.InvoiceDate = 5
```

which does work.

Does anyone know what I can use to assign a value to a class property in VBA when using a variable to reference the property name?

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax for assignments using CallByName. See  the examples here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `CallByName(oThisInvoice, DataType, VbGet) = 5`

Of course that doesn't work to set a value. You are calling a `Get` procedure, as evidenced by the use of `VbGet`. Get doesn't set values, it gets them.

What you need to do instead is use `CallByName` with `VbLet`:

```
CallByName oThisInvoice, DataType, VbLet, 5
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have pasted an older version: I did try both VbLet and VbSet (both gave Error 446: Object doesn't support named arguments).  I did try your different syntax, though, and got the error: "Run-Time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.  I'll update the original post with the errors I got with VbLet and VbSet

Comment: If you use the same syntax but with VbLet, it works!  If you change your answer to reflect that I will mark it correct.

Comment: Oh, right, `Let` for a value as opposed to `Set` for an object. My bad.